# Unable to assign function results to array indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have a function called `simulate_ant()` that returns a fitness value of a simulated ant on a 32x32 grid, it takes as parameters a text file for the grid and a string consisting of 30 digits which make up a finite state machine, 10 states each represented by 3 digits.

I've created an array of 30 digit strings and I would like to iterate through this 10 times and populate a separate array with the results of the function, to do this I wrote this code:

```
% our first generation of ants
first_gen = ['110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100'];
first_gen_fitness = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

% get fitnesses of first generation of ants
for i = 1:10

    first_gen_fitness(i) = simulate_ant('muir_world.txt', first_gen(i));

end
```

What I'm expected is for `first_gen_fitness` to be populated with 10 47's like so: `first_gen_fitness = [47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47];` but instead it just comes out with 10 0's.

Could someone please show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What does `simulate_ant('muir_world.txt', first_gen(1))` return? Run the code manually, one step at a time (without using the for loop) to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: It returned the same error I would get if I ran `simulate_ant('muir_world.txt', 1);` which is essentially telling me that I've not input the correct second parameter. However if I run `simulate_ant('muir_world.txt', '110202132224154246176368198100');` I get the correct answer of 47, but don't both of those represent exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is:

`first_gen(1) == '1'`, not `'110202132224154246176368198100'`

You can for instance do:

```
first_gen(i,:)
```

to get the entire first row. So in total:

```
% our first generation of ants
first_gen = ['110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100';'110202132224154246176368198100'];
first_gen_fitness = zeros(10,1)

% get fitnesses of first generation of ants
for ii = 1:10
    first_gen_fitness(ii) = simulate_ant('muir_world.txt', first_gen(i,:));
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.